# error in libs folder - android

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, libs

I was working on my app, editing and coding some xml and layouts when suddenly I got an error on my libs folder. It's very weird because I haven't actually modified or changed any base classes or something. Moreover, I just noticed I lost also my R.java file and all of the references are gone.

What possibly can be the problem? I tried to clean+build the project but it didn't work.
Here is a screenshot of my eclipse:
http://i.gyazo.com/959040321d1fd6d00ee0b9a90133aa9c.png

Comment: just wanting to know, what is there in the libs folder?

Comment: there is a jar file called android-support-v4.jar

Comment: libs is placed at wrong location man..!!

Comment: this is not the place to put the jar

Comment: libs goes at the same directory level as res, not in res

Answer (score 0):

Place the jar in the root folder of your project. Then you can add it to your classpath . (you cannot place a jar and access it using android.R) 
You can add the jars to your build path by right clicking on your project->properties and going to Build Path. Then you can add an external jar

Comment: could you elaborate on that? I tried to do what you said but I still have an error on my project. I placed my libs folder at the same directory level as res folder.

Comment: after placing it there, go to libraries(in the build path dialog), and go to add jars. Then select your jar.

Do you have remote desktop connection ?I ll show it to you .

Comment: Never mind dude, I succeeded to do what you told me and it works! Thank you so much :)